# jQuery Validation - Is there a way to set the validation rule 'required' with a function?

Tags: jquery, validation, required

I have a form module that may be called in different circumstances and depending on those circumstances, I need to change the required validation rule. This is my rule block:

```
$( "#frmProfile" ).validate( {
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    pass: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    firstName: "required",
    lastName: "required",
    phone: {
      required: req('phone'); // **This is one of my attempts**
      phoneUS: true
    },
    cellPhone: {
      required: false,
      phoneUS: true
    }               
  },    
  messages: { .....
```

I created a function to query a list of required fields that I generate when the form is loaded.

```
function req(field) {
  if ( jQuery.inArray( field, reqFields ) >= 0 ) {
    return true 
  } else {
    return false
  }             
}
```

But it seems to bomb on the ";" in the rule. I have also tried the '{depends:' option but that didn't work either. 
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I changed the following element and it now works. Thanks to the person that pointed me in the right direction but whose name I can't see from this edit screen. ;-)

```
    phone: { 
      required: function() { 
        return jQuery.inArray( 'phone', reqFields ) >= 0;
      },    
      phoneUS: true
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the function in the required object as shown in the docs http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/? you do not need to return true or false you can simply return the result ie. `phone: { required: function(field) { return jQuery.inArray( field, reqFields ) >= 0;`

Comment: Thanks Alessi, That seemed to fix it.